# mysql how to join a table and do some math

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables, rolls and rollsout. I would like to perform a join and do some math .

rolls

```
      |size|
      ------
      |3x3| 
      |4x4| 
      |3x3| 
      |3x3|
```

rollsout

```
      |type|
      ------
      |3x3|
```

Expected output after SUBTRACTing, JOINing  ==>

```
      |size|Remaining(table1 - table2)|
      --------------------------------
      |3x3|   2                       |                 
      |4x4|   1                       |
```

My code:

```
SELECT tarpaulin.size, COUNT( * ) , tarpaulinout.Ww, tarpaulinout.dc 
FROM tarpaulin LEFT JOIN (SELECT size AS Ww, COUNT( * ) AS dc FROM tarpaulinout 
GROUP BY size) AS tarpaulinout ON tarpaulin.size = tarpaulinout.Ww 
GROUP BY tarpaulin.size
```

But the O/P for the above code is

```
      |size|count(*)|size |dc    |
      ----------------------------
      |3x3|3        | 3x3 |1     |
      |4x4|1        | NILL| NILL |
```

i can get this close, kindly instruct me on how to achieve my desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How do you expect to get 2 after subtracting 100 from 100?

Comment: my bad. hope u will understand now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just UNION the two sets together, then take a SUM across both, i.e.

```
select size, sum(counter) remaining
from
(
    select size, 1 counter
    from rolls
    union all
    select type, -1 counter
    from rollsout
) x
group by size;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the first table and second table separately on `size` to get the count of records and then perform a LEFT JOIN on the `size` attribute to get all the records from `tarpaulin` table and the matching ones from `tarpaulinout` table, and do the subtraction, as below.

```
SELECT a.size, a.rcount - ISNULL(b.rcount, 0)
FROM
    (SELECT size, count(*) FROM tarpaulin GROUP BY size) as a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT size, count(*) FROM tarpaulinout GROUP BY size) as b
    ON a.size = b.size
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select x.Size,(x.Cnt1 - Isnull(y.Cnt2, 0)) AS Remaining
From
(Select r.Size,count(r.Size) Cnt1
From rolls r
Group by r.Size)x

Left Outer join
(Select ro.Type,Count(ro.Type) Cnt2
From rollsout ro
Group by ro.Type)y

On x.Size = y.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.size, a.Rcount - b.Acount FROM (SELECT size, COUNT( * ) AS Rcount FROM tarpaulin GROUP BY size ) AS a LEFT JOIN ( SELECT size, COUNT( * ) AS Acount FROM tarpaulinout GROUP BY size ) AS b ON a.size = b.size
```

A little modification to Vikdor code worked for me thanks for the quick input guys :)